# how to dynamically allocate memory for a struct type array in C

Tags: c, memory, struct

so I have a program where I need to read a file and store some words from it in an array, but I want to do it so that in each array in which I store the respective words to have custom size depending on how many words I have

```
typedef struct {
    char* keyword;
    int keywordCount;
    int stdev;
} keywordData;

int keywordNumber;

keywordData* keyword;

void fetchKeywords(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* keywords = fopen(filename, "r");
    // first number in the file is the number of keywords in the file, so i dont need to count them
    fscanf(keywords,"%d", &keywordNumber);

    keyword = (keywordData *) malloc(keywordNumber * sizeof(keywordData));

    for(int i = 0; i < keywordNumber; i++)
    {
        fscanf(keywords,"%s", keyword[i].keyword);
        //printf("%s\n", keyword[i].keyword);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(keywords,"%s", keyword[i].keyword);` invokes undefined behavior. `keyword[i].keyword` is an indeterminate pointer that has no memory behind it reserved for your storage.

Comment: Why is `keyword` a pointer instead of an array?

Comment: @Barmar from examples online that's how i've seen other people allocate memory for struct type arrays

Comment: @WhozCraig so how can i allocate memory for storage?

Comment: You use a pointer if the size can be variable. But if you're using `scanf()` you need to allocate a buffer for the string first, so it will never be bigger than the buffer you allocate. You might as well just declare a string with that length.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid as you did not allocate memory for `keyword` and you scan the string into it. It invokes undefined behaviour UB.

Try not to use global variables. Use function return values and if needed pointer parameters.

```
#define MAXKEYWORDLENGTH 64

typedef struct {
    char keyword[MAXKEYWORDLENGTH];
    int keywordCount;
    int stdev;
} keywordData;


keywordData *fetchKeywords(const char* filename, int *keywordNumber)
{
    FILE* keywords = fopen(filename, "r");
    keywordData *kd;
    // first number in the file is the number of keywords in the file, so i dont need to count them
    if(keywords) 
       if(fscanf(keywords,"%d", keywordNumber) != 1) { /* error handling*/}

    kd = malloc(*keywordNumber * sizeof(*kd));

    if(kd)
        for(int i = 0; i < keywordNumber; i++)
        {
            fscanf(keywords,"%s", kd[i].keyword);
            //printf("%s\n", keyword[i].keyword);
        }
    if(keywords) fclose(keywords);
    return kd;
}
```

Comment: so for this line ```for(int i = 0; i < keywordNumber; i++)``` i get this warning: ```comparison between pointer and integer;```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but the warning you're getting with the other answer's code is because `keywordNumber` is an `int *` whereas `i` is just an `int`, so you need to dereference `keywordNumber` first in the for loop (so `for (int i = 0; i < *keywordNumber; i++)`); this code should fix it:

```
#define MAXKEYWORDLENGTH 64

typedef struct {
    char keyword[MAXKEYWORDLENGTH];
    int keywordCount;
    int stdev;
} keywordData;


keywordData *fetchKeywords(const char* filename, int *keywordNumber)
{
    FILE* keywords = fopen(filename, "r");
    keywordData *kd;
    // first number in the file is the number of keywords in the file, so i dont need to count them
    if(keywords) 
       if(fscanf(keywords,"%d", keywordNumber) != 1) { /* error handling*/}

    kd = malloc(*keywordNumber * sizeof(*kd));

    if(kd)
        for(int i = 0; i < *keywordNumber; i++)
        {
            fscanf(keywords,"%s", kd[i].keyword);
            //printf("%s\n", keyword[i].keyword);
        }
    if(keywords) fclose(keywords);
    return kd;
}
```